# Traveling on another passport while waiting for US visa to process

Tags: visas, usa, dual-nationality

I am a citizen of two countries: Ireland and Australia. I live in the US on a visa and I am currently in Ireland renewing said visa. The US consulate is currently processing the renewal and possess my Australian passport. Will me traveling around Europe on my Irish passport cause any issues while the visa is in process?

Comment: No you will be fine

Answer (score 2):

No, as an Irish citizen you're guaranteed absolute freedom of movement within the EU. You may travel, live and work in any EU country without as much as mentioning your Australian documents. Enjoy your trip :)